# Cassandra Materialized View Creation Speedup

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to create a Materialized-View on an existing cassandra table with 1200K+ records.
Its been a couple of hours since i executed the query for view creation, but still I find the row count to be 0 in the view.

I have already tried nodetool flush keyspace-name.

Is there a way to find out where it is stuck? or what is the progress?
Is there any way to speed this up?